# Fourier Series in $L^1$ and $L^2$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\Omega = [0, 1)$ with Lebesgue measure.

If $f\in L^2 (\Omega)$ and we have the following series

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n \exp(2 \pi i n x),$$

where $i =\sqrt{-1}$, then can we use this series for $f\in L^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: If you call $a_n=\int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2\pi in x}\,dx$, then that series converges pointwise almost everywhere (Carleson and Hunt) and in $L^p$ to $f$ as soon as $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ for some $p\in(1,\infty)$. For $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ there are counterexamples to both (Kolmogorov). [This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28428/convergence-of-fourier-series-of-l1-functions) has a few links (not necessarily the best ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f \in L^{2}$ the infinite sum is interpreted as a sum in the $L^{2}$ norm sense. For $f \in L^{1}$ the series need not converge w.r.t either the $L^{1}$ norm or the $L^{2}$ norm.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\in L^2[0,1]$, and if the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{2\pi int}$ converges in $L^2$ to $f$, then $f\in L^1$ and
$$
        \|f-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}c_ne^{2\pi nt}\|_{L^1}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}c_ne^{2\pi int}|dt \\
       \le \left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1^2dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}c_ne^{2\pi nt}|^2\right)^{1/2}\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } N\rightarrow\infty.
$$